# Unable to load Biobliography using {biblatex} package and \printbibliography

Tags: latex, bibliography

This is the code I use for my bibliography

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

\printbibliography

This is an example of my bibliopgrahy:

```
@Article{Acosta2008,author = {Acosta, EG and Castilla, V and Damonte, EB}, title = {Functional entry of dengue virus into Aedes albopictusmosquito cells is dependent on clathrin-mediated endocytosis.}, journal = {J Gen Virol}, volume = {89}, number = {Pt 2}, pages = {474--484}, year = {2008}, abstract = {Entry of dengue virus 2 (DENV-2) into Aedes albopictus mosquito C6/36 cells was analysed using biochemical and molecular inhibitors, together with confocal and electron microscopy observations. Treatment with monodansylcadaverine, chlorpromazine, sucrose and ammonium chloride inhibited DENV-2 virus yield and protein expression, whereas nystatin, a blocker of caveolae-mediated endocytosis, did not have any effect. Using confocal microscopy, co-localization of DENV-2 E glycoprotein and the marker protein transferrin was observed at the periphery of the cytoplasm. To support the requirement of clathrin function for DENV-2 entry, overexpression of a dominant-negative mutant of Eps15 in C6/36 cells was shown to impair virus entry. The disruption of actin microfilaments by cytochalasin D also significantly affected DENV-2 replication. In contrast, microtubule disruption by colchicine treatment did not impair DENV-2 infectivity, suggesting that DENV-2 does not require transport from early to late endosomes for successful infection of mosquito cells. Furthermore, using transmission electron microscopy, DENV-2 particles of approximately 44-52 nm were found attached within electron-dense invaginations of the plasma membrane and in coated vesicles that resembled those of clathrin-coated pits and vesicles, respectively. Together, these results demonstrate for the first time that DENV-2 enters insect cells by receptor-mediated, clathrin-dependent endocytosis, requiring traffic through an acidic pH compartment for subsequent uncoating and completion of a productive infection.}, location = {}, keywords = {}}
```

I have tried several ways to load the bibliography stored in my bibliography.bib file with no results.

The error is:

> Empty bibliography on input line

The bibliography is not empty, and the bibligraphy is on the same folder as the main '.tex' file

Comment: Error or warning? http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Empty+bibliography+on+input+line%22

Comment: It has a warning sign

Answer (score 2):

If your bibliography with the above content is bibliography.bib, and the following

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

Text ... citation: \cite{Acosta2008}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

is main.tex in the same folder, then you should have no problem.

Make sure that you compile once, then you compile the bibliography with **Biber**, then you compile the tex one last time.

Confront your minimal code with mine but - mainly - check in the settings of your editor that **Biber**, not **BibTex**, is used to build the bibliography (example: [TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02a)).

Comment: Thanks, but the in-text citation does appear, however \printbibliography does not print the bibliography. It still says that is it is empty

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. But it worked for me when I deleted the whole `[]` at `usepackage`.

So, for `\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}`, I deleted the middle part so there only was `\usepackage{biblatex}`. I ran it and it worked. After that, I could use this one again `\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}` and it worked too.